# I'm looking for an excel formula to get a count of unique client ID's when a condition in another column are all met

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unique, countif

I have a data set that looks like this:

| Date | Client ID | Successful outcome (y/n) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/21 | AAA | Y |
| 1/2/21 | AAA | N |
| 1/3/21 | AAA | N |
| 1/1/21 | BBB | N |
| 1/2/21 | BBB | N |
| 1/2/21 | CCC | N |
| 1/3/21 | CCC | N |
| 1/4/21 | CCC | N |
| 1/1/21 | DDD | Y |
| 1/4/21 | DDD | Y |

I need to find a unique count where all records for a client was No. If at any point, an outcome was yes, then that unique client ID would not be included in the count.

I tried using variations of different formulas I found online:

```
=SUM(--(LEN(UNIQUE(FILTER('Table[Client ID],'Table[Successful Outcome (y/n)]="No")))>0))
=COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER('Table[Client ID],'Table[Successful Outcome (y/n)]="No")))
```

However I'm not able to get the count to exclude a client ID entirely if there is a "yes" for that client. In the sample above, Client A should not be included in the unique count because there is a "Yes" value.

I ended going brute force where I sorted the table by Client ID, highlighted duplicates, and then deleted all the client records when there was a yes and a no.

What I was left with was a table of duplicate client records where all successful outcomes were No, along with the other non-duplicate records of Yes's and No's. I then filtered for No's and from there I deleted the duplicates in the Client ID column.

Comment: So Why `"No"` when you data shows `N`

Answer (score 1):

Use Let and another FILTER and MATCH to remove the ones that have a `Y`:

```
=LET(x,FILTER(Table[Client ID],(Table[Successful outcome (y/n)]="N")*(ISERROR(MATCH(Table[Client ID],FILTER(Table[Client ID],Table[Successful outcome (y/n)]="y",""),0))),""),IF(@x="",0,COUNTA(UNIQUE(x))))
```

[image]

Comment: EDIT: The actual Client ID in my data set is numeric. That's why I used the COUNT as opposed to COUNTA. 

The return I was looking for was 2 unique Client ID's where all outcomes were 'No.' Client AAA has a yes so it would NOT be included in the count. 
Client BBB is counted. 
Client CCC is counted. 
Client DDD is not counted.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2:B11,FILTER(B2:B11,C2:C11="Y"),)),"",B2:B11&"")))-1
```